# How is `@babel/runtime` implemented so that it can reference dependency outside `node_modules`?

Tags: javascript, package.json, babel-polyfill

From [these lines on GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/dfa4cc652718e1ce7905eaa2260cafa3392e052f/packages/babel-runtime/package.json#L218_L226), they're referencing the regenerator runtime:

```json
    "./helpers/regeneratorRuntime": [
      {
        "node": "./helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js",
        "import": "./helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js",
        "default": "./helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js"
      },
      "./helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js"
    ],
    "./helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime": "./helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js",
```

but if you see the [source code folder](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-runtime) there is nowhere you can find the files `./helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js` or `./helpers/esm/regeneratorRuntime.js`.

So how is this be done?

Comment: [yes you can](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-helpers/src/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js). Standard "the source and the distributable don't live in the same dir" practice.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But where is the script they use to generate these file?

Comment: I think you forgot to read he [CONTRIBUTING.md file](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md), which exist specifically to explain how the project works in terms of the code itself for people who want to understand how to work on it, including how to build it and giving  you the starting points to then pursue yourself. A project this big and popular has plenty of docs to explain itself, but you do need to read them ;)